# Does PHP duplicate objects on assignment?

Tags: php

Does PHP duplicate an object when `=` is used or does it just create a new pointer that points to an already existing object?

Are both of these the same?

```
$obj1 = new object(); 
$obj2 = $obj1;

$obj1 = new object(); 
$obj2 = clone $obj1;
```

Comment: If it was Javascript, yes. It should just capture the current value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP 4 (i.e. ancient history) objects were indeed copied on assignment.  This was not helpful behaviour.

Since PHP 5, objects are now assigned by reference, unless they are cloned.

You can easily test this:

```
$obj1 = new object(); 
$obj2 = $obj1;
var_dump($obj1 === $obj2); // bool(true)

$obj1 = new object(); 
$obj2 = clone $obj1;
var_dump($obj1 === $obj2); // bool(false)
```

Comment: This royally pissed me off the other week - the docs should make absolutely clear that objects aren't cloned whilst _everything else is_

Comment: @Bojangles It's a bit more complicated than that, really... http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php